# Paster make-config is deprecated and rhodecode-config not known

Tags: python, paster, rhodecode

I'm trying to create production.ini file for rhodecode based on this [tutorial](http://www.eis.ms/posts/2013/april/04/complete-guide-to-install-and-configure-rhodecode-on-ubuntu-1204-using-mysql.aspx). But paster gives the following error:

```
** Warning ** 
This command is now removed and deprecated, please use new rhodecode-config command instead.
```

When I try to use paster rhodecode-config, it says that `Command 'rhodecode-config' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)` and gives the list of available commands, where 'rhodecode-config' is not listed.

How can I solve this? And which `setup.py` does it talk about. I installed the rhodecode with pip, so I don't have any source code.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I used @qingbo's link - which he posted in the comments - and tried to install `rhodecode-tools` but I'm still getting `rhodecode-config not known` error. BTW, I saw in the lines of installation that `rhodecode-config` is installed into `venv/bin`. What could be the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at this URL: https://rhodecode.com/help/discussions/problems/6836-cannot-find-rhodecode-config-command

Comment: I used the information there after you posted it, but no luck. it still gives the same error. In fact, there was a small complication with `mako` version(`rhodecode-tools` installs `0.9.0`, but paster wants `0.9.1` exactly). I installed `mako v0.9.1` via `pip`, and tried again but same error (not known), and it gives list of available commands with no `rhodecode-config` in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those things in those tutorials are deprecated.

Please goto https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Control/tasks/install.html for new installation instructions. With RhodeCode new installer it's much simpler to do installation and upgrades